# Excel VBA - macro filling rows with numbers 1 to 3 exceeds desired range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have stumbled upon a problem which solution seems to be very close but I still can't get it.
Code below is supposed to fill specific cells with a number between 1,2,3 so it looks like

1. row2 (as it starts from row2) - 1
2. row3 - 2
3. row4 - 3
4. row5 - 1
5. row6 - 2
6. ...

Let's say that "range" variable returns 700 rows. I'd like to have above numbers in specified order only in these 700 rows however when I run the code pasted below it returns 3 times more filled cells. I'm more than certain it's somewhere in either first For or the inner one but I can't still bite it correctly :(

```vb
Sub level()
    
        Set sf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("formatted")
        Dim range As Long
            range = sf.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
           
        x = 2
        
        For i = 2 To range
            For y = 1 To 3
            
                sf.Cells(x, 9).Value = y
                sf.Cells(x, 11).Value = y
                x = x + 1
                
            Next y
        Next i
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you not using `i` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use Mod:

```
Sub level()

    Set sf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("formatted")

    Dim rng As Long
    rng = sf.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
       
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To rng
        sf.Cells(i, 9) = ((i - 2) Mod 3) + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe use a different variable name than `Range` too...

Comment: Yeah, I do use different variable names, no worries. Just put it in here to keep it a ltitle bit discreet :)

Comment: @mtvsh yes, but you could have just as easily used `lastRow` as a variable name.

Comment: Ugggh... `Dim rng As Long` just looks soooo wrong lol.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. I'm like a crawling baby when it comes to VBA, thereby I apologize :)